# Correct lag() of column associated with an observation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row

I have a data frame as below, where I create a lagged column by using `lag()` on the observed values in the `values` column. Each row in my data frame is associated to a specific journey. I would like to correct the `lag()` operation as now, it doesn't consider if the `value` is the first on a new journey, meaning there should be no previous recording. Then I want to drop that row from my data frame.

By running the df_output, the desired output can be observed, but now it's done manually.

My real data frame contains a large amount of rows, and in turn journeys.

```
# Reproducible example
df <- data.frame(tours = c("kuu122", "kuu122", "ansc123123", "ansc123123", "ansc123123", "ansc123123", "baa3999", "baa3999", "baa3999", "baa3999"), order = c(4, 5, rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2)), journey = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), values = c(50, 60, 10, 20, 15, 13, 28, 15, 22, 14))

# Get the observed values at order_t
observed_values <- df$values
# Create lagged column
df$prev_values <- lag(observed_values, 1)

# TODO
# Remove row if prev_values are the first observation on a new journey
#???


df_output <- df[c(2, 4:6, 8:10),]
df_output
```

Comment: is that `stats::lag` or `dplyr::lag`?

Comment: it's `dplyr::lag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R` with `duplicated`

```
subset(df, duplicated(journey))
```

-output

```
         tours order journey values
2      kuu122     5       1     60
4  ansc123123     2       2     20
5  ansc123123     3       2     15
6  ansc123123     4       2     13
8     baa3999     2       3     15
9     baa3999     3       3     22
10    baa3999     4       3     14
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the idea with using base R, and the logic behind the code is appealing. Appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting all but the first row by group with `row_number`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  filter(row_number() != 1, .by = tours)
       tours order journey values
1     kuu122     5       1     60
2 ansc123123     2       2     20
3 ansc123123     3       2     15
4 ansc123123     4       2     13
5    baa3999     2       3     15
6    baa3999     3       3     22
7    baa3999     4       3     14
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `slice` for this:

```
library(dplyr)

df_output <- df %>%
  group_by(journey) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

or with dplyr >=1.1.0

```
df %>%
  slice(-1, .by=journey)
```